# How do I set a background on a view without affecting its dimensions?

Tags: java, android

I want use a tiled background to give a texture to an existing layout. So I have created a drawable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/green-linen"
    android:tileMode="repeat" >
</bitmap>
```

Where "green-linen.jpg" is a 800x800 texture that I want to use. Then where I wish to use it on a layout I set background to point to this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/background">
```

The problem is now the layout thinks it needs to be 800x800 to accomodate the pattern which screws up the design. Is there any way to set a background but without affecting the existing layout? Plan B would probably be to write a custom paint routine but it likely to be more work and less efficient than just styling the page or setting the drawable.

Comment: What's the goal of using a tiled background if it's larger than the container?

Comment: The container might be larger, it might be smaller. Depends on the device the app is running on.

Answer (score 0):

The setBackground command will only affect the size of the view if you use 'wrap_content' as the layout parameter. If you want the view to be of fixed size, specify that size as the layout parameter and then changing the background will not affect the view size.

Comment: Sounds like I have to custom paint then. The existing layout has been designed to not hardcode dimensions and tolerate adjustments to its contents.